# Variable pointer to interface between C# and C++

Tags: c#, c++

I am currently stuck trying to do this conversion. I have a C++ wrapper that exposes a function...

```
public __gc class InternalModuleConfig : public ModuleConfig
{
Object* InternalModuleConfig::CommitChanges(IModuleConfig* config)
{
    VARIANT variant = {0};
    m_pModuleConfig = config;
    HRESULT hr = m_pModuleConfig->CommitChanges(&variant);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        VariantClear(&variant);
        return Marshal::GetObjectForNativeVariant(&variant);
    }

    return NULL;
};
};
```

I am trying to call this function in c# but failing at it. I have an interface in C# with the following namespace:

DirectShow.IModuleConfig

Now I am trying to take my existing interface and get a pointer to it to use as the variable for CommitChanges in C# however I always get an conversion error.

This is the barebone with what I'm trying...

```
InternalModuleConfig config;
config.CommitChanges(ref (filter as IModuleConfig));
```

This does not work... I'm a bit confused as to how to apply the type IModuleConfig* for the parameter.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
This is the interface the InternalModuleConfig is based on:

```
public __gc interface ModuleConfig : public IDisposable
{
public:
virtual Object* CommitChanges(IModuleConfig* config) = 0;
IModuleConfig* m_pModuleConfig;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has been awhile since I've done C++/CLI but if you intend to have a C# ref param I believe you need a point to a pointer in C++.

```
Object* InternalModuleConfig::CommitChanges(IModuleConfig** config)
```

Every object in the managed heap is accessed by a pointer. In order to allow the pointer to be changed within the function (ref semantics) you need a pointer to that pointer.

Or conversely if you are not intending to use `ref` semantics remove that modifier on the C# side and you should be able to pass the managed object.

Answer (score 2):

When exposing a C++/CLI interface to C#, you must use tracking handles instead of pointers or references:

```
virtual Object^ CommitChanges( IModuleConfig^% config) = 0;
```

(The argument's syntax represents a tracking handle passed by reference, which is the C++/CLI equivalent to C#'s ref parameters)

Comment: I'm using clr/oldsyntax and it doesn't support the tracking handles... any way aroundt this?

Comment: I have to keep it set to oldsyntax because of the dependencies in the 3rd party header file.

Answer (score 1):

That won't work; what would happen if the method puts a different `IModuleConfig` implementation in the field?

Instead, use the correct variable type:

```
IModuleConfig config = something;
config.CommitChanges(ref filter as IModuleConfig);
```

Comment: This still doesn't work... I updated my question with the interface in C++... the error I get in c# is cannot convert from 'ref DirectShow.IModuleConfig' to 'IModuleConfig' however... the Directshow implmentation is based off of the same IModuleConfig.

Comment: @bl4kh4k: You need to use the _same_ type, not a compatible type.  C# is not duck typed.

Comment: I cannot use the CommitChanges that is part of the IModuleConfig because in C# the VARIANT variable that it originally takes in is not supported. So I decided to write a wrapper that would ultimately override the function from ModuleConfig interface that takes in the IModuleConfig* pointer. Maybe I'm not understanding your solution correctly?

Comment: @bl4kh4k "in C# the VARIANT variable that it originally takes in is not supported" -- `object` is used for this, it is converted from/to `VARIANT`.

Comment: @hvd: I thought so, however I didn't create the original IModuleConfig... its actually a MainConcept interface to tap into the properties of an MP4 Muxer. I set it to Object, and every other function works this way however CommitChanges is the only one that doesn't work with the Object type and just returns an HRESULT of invalid parameter.